# Identifying the failed item from a list in bulk transactions

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, design-patterns

Am trying to batch a list of items into single transaction like below

```
Lists.partition(new ArrayList()<>(customer),100).parallelStream().forEach(customers->{
                    UserTransaction userTransaction = new UserTransactionImp();
                    try {
                        userTransaction.begin();
                        for(String cus : customers){
                            //code to write to db 
                        }
                        userTransaction.commit();
                    } catch (Exception exception) {

                        //collect the failed list and re partition them into smaller lists say 50
                    }
```

But i dont want to fail all the 100 just because few faulty accounts.I am thinking to collect the failed items into one more list and partition further into small list .I can do this normally by invoking parallel stream again.But i wanted to know if there is any design pattern to solve this

Comment: `customer.removeIf(c -> /**Some condition**/);` to remove all of the customers with an error. Then run your code.

Comment: Am looking for design patter if any

Comment: place `try...catch` block inside `for` loop. This way you can collect failed transactions.

Comment: there might be failure when  userTransaction.commit(); is invoked

Comment: @pppavan it your transaction encloses the whole loop, it's either all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could force a *chain of responsibility pattern* here:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility

Creating a chain of handlers that delegate to the next one in case of failure.
Seems like an overkill but allows future extensibility.